# ci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed

Tags: php, laravel, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I am using Laravel 5 with [yajra/laravel-oci8](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8) . Problem is that I am getting this error:

```
ErrorException in Oci8.php line 81:
oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries
```

I edited System Environment variables, activated OCI8 in php.ini and tried everything that I could find on Google but none of that worked...

[image: Environment Variables]
[image: php.ini]
[image]

EDIT: Added PHP Enviroments:

[image: PHP Enviroments]
Does someone knows where's the problem?

Comment: What does the `Environment` section of your phpinfo look like?

Comment: @patricus I edited my post. If you cant read picture, open it in new tab and it will be readable

Comment: You have what looks like an Oracle 8i installation - `C:\ORANT\bin` - in your path.  Oracle libraries don't mix well so perhaps try removing that from the path.

Comment: @timclutton Thank you for your help. I tried your suggestion and it didn't worked.